# $$Hashkey missing when trying to add object with push from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

Array with hardcoded object shows up in my ng-repeat.

```
  $scope.deltagarelist = [{ label: "Nils", value: "3" }];
```

This is my javascript/angular hybrid code to get selected values from the autocomplete and push it into my objectarray.

```
  $(".addDeltagare").autocomplete(
{
    source: function (request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { query: request.term },
            datatype: 'jsonp',

            success: function (data) {


                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {

                        label: item.Label,
                        value: item.Value
                    }
                }));
            }


        });


    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();

        addtolist(ui.item);
        console.log($scope.deltagarelist);

        $(this).val('');

    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#addDeltagare").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }

});
```

And my function to push the object into my list.

```
function addtolist(item) {

$scope.deltagarelist.push({label:item.label,value:item.value});
```

}

My problem is that my hardcoded guy "Nils" gets a $$hashkey but when I add an object to the list in this way it doesnt get a hashkey and it adds to the array but doesnt show up in my repeat.
Any ideas on how I can change this code to make it work?
Or should I look for other autcompletes thats more "the angular way" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is adding a `track by` to your `ng-repeat` so that AngularJS doesn't need to use the `$$hashkey` to track changes.

```
<div ng-repeat="val in deltagarelist track by val.value">
```

Comment: Also I had to add $scope.$apply() inside of my addtolist() function.


thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The $ajax is asynchronous, this means the NG-app is already been build before the data is downloaded. A workaround is to make $ajax sync sothat everything waits until the data is downloaded.